# OpenAPI spec generated from FastAPI not showing missing values allowed as dict values

Tags: python, fastapi, openapi, pydantic

Take this simple service:

```
# main.py

import typing as t

from pydantic.types import StrictStr

from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel, StrictBool, StrictInt, StrictStr

Value = t.Optional[StrictBool] | t.Optional[StrictInt]

class Example(BaseModel):
    x: dict[StrictStr, Value]

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/read", response_model=Example)
def read():
    return Example(x={"value": None})
```

the actual service works as intended:

```
$ curl localhost:8000/read | jq
{
  "x": {
    "value": null
  }
}
```

The issue is with the `openapi.json` and how it's translating the `Example` class -- it doesn't seem to allow `null` values:

```
$ curl localhost:8000/openapi.json | jq '.components'
{
  "schemas": {
    "Example": {
      "title": "Example",
      "required": [
        "x"
      ],
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "x": {
          "title": "X",
          "type": "object",
          "additionalProperties": {
            "anyOf": [
              {
                "type": "boolean"
              },
              {
                "type": "integer"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is a problem because when I use it to generate client libraries, they fail on validating the output with something like

```
ApiValueError: Invalid inputs given to generate an instance of <class>. None of the anyOf schemas matched the input data.
```

Any solutions here?

Comment: This is an [issue](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/1270) of how Pydantic generates the JSON schema for nullable fields that has been known for quite a while. It looks like this will be fixed in [version 2](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/milestone/2) of Pydantic, which may still take a while. Though that specific problem might be fixed before v2, I would not count on it. But the issue I linked shows a few possible workarounds for now.

Comment: thanks, the workaround in the issue should work for me